# How do I make an object face the mouse position, but only on one plane?

Tags: 2d, 3d, unity, rotation, lerp

I want a game object to turn and look towards where the mouse was clicked (in world space).  It works well when considering all 3 dimensions, but I really only care for the plane formed by the `x` and `z` axis, not the `y`.

I've tried to fix this by setting the `y` of the `directionTarget` to the `y` of the object's position, but that gives weird results.

My code looks like this:

```
Quaternion rotationTarget;
    float rotationLerpProgress;
    float rotationLerpDuration = 1f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
                    RaycastHit rayHit; 
                    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out rayHit)) {
                            var rayHitPoint = rayHit.point; 
                            var rotationDirection = transform.position - rayHitPoint;                               
                            rotationDirection.Normalize ();
                            //rotationDirection.y = transform.position.y;
                            rotationTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation (rotationDirection);
                            rotationLerpProgress = Time.deltaTime;
                    }
                    //targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);                        
            }

            if (rotationTarget != transform.rotation) {

                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, rotationTarget, rotationLerpProgress / rotationLerpDuration);
                    rotationLerpProgress += Time.deltaTime; 

                    if (rotationLerpProgress >= rotationLerpDuration) {

                            transform.rotation = rotationTarget;
                    }

            }

    }
```

I must be missing something. How do I do this right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move player to mouse click](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69444/move-player-to-mouse-click)

Comment: @Roberto: that question is entirely about a 2D-only world while this one is about mapping 3D rotation deltas to a plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd project the rotationDirection into the horizontal plane before you normalize it, something like...

```
var rotationDirection = transform.position - rayHitPoint;
```

**rotationDirection.y = 0;**

```
rotationDirection.Normalize ();
rotationTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation (rotationDirection);
```

Note that the order of the subtraction used to define your rotationDirection there results in a vector *from* the rayHitPoint *to* transform.position, not the other way - is that as intended?

Comment: Also, you don't actually need to normalize before calling Quaternion.LookRotation() - it handles working with non-unit vectors just fine (it may normalize a second time internally)

Comment: Great! Ive learned something. I was using rotationDirection.y = transform.position.y; but instead i should have: rotationDirection.y = 0;
Also the normalisation is not nescessary. 

I had done  var rotationDirection = transform.position - rayHitPoint; but it should be the other way, as you pointed out. :) THANKS!

Comment: @Lautaro I suggest you pick a good vector/matrices tutorial/book and study that for a while. Those skills are essensial for game development otherwise you will struggle if you want to make more complicated things. Sorry If I sound arrogant, that's only an advice and not meant to offense anyone.

Comment: @concept3d i agree. Im just trying to learn by doing small experiments. Im not doing a game just figuring out how to make stuff happen while i read tutorials. Care to recommend a good book for beginners?

Comment: @Lautaro this one is good for beginners, it's not the best, but good enough to start with http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Graphics-Development-Wordware-Library/dp/1556229119/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y